# The benefit of using generics over data-type specific methods in searches and sorts?

Tags: java

what is the benefit of using the generic version of the searches(binary,sequential) and sorts(bubble,selection,insertion,quick) over the other data-type specific searches and sorts.

Comment: Would you like to overload those methods for different datatypes? The benefit is you get a single recipe to serve different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clutters your code with unnecessary duplicates... One code that runs on every data-type is better than adding a new copy of code every time you need it to run for another data-type.

Assuming you had a data-type specific sort, and made 5 copies per data-type you need to sort. What if you need to modify something? You need to go and change all 5 copies... Generics were created just to solve this problem.

If a solution can be generalized without compromising its integrity, why not generalize?